# Проблема с генерацией .dacbac файла

Tags: sql, sql-server

Заказчики поставили задачу обновить БД через dacpac. С данной технологией ранее не работали. В процессе генерации файла получили ворох ошибок. Но, если конкретизировать, то ошибки 71564 и 71561. Содержание следующее (Приведу для примера по одному сообщению, чтобы не растягивать сообщение):

Error SQL71564: Error validating element [Indusoft]: The element [Indusoft] has been orphaned from its login and cannot be deployed.
Error SQL71561: Error validating element [dbo].[v_SampleReportValue2]: View: [dbo].[v_SampleReportValue2] has an unresolved reference to object [I-LDS RN SNPZ].[dbo].[v_TestResult].
Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[v_TTRange]: View: [dbo].[v_TTRange] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[TechTestLimit].[TTRange], [dbo].[TTBoundaryPoint].[TTRange], [dbo].[TTRange].[TechTestVerId], [dbo].[TTRange].[TTRange] or [dbo].[TTRangeItem].[TTRange].

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что нужно сделать для решения данной проблемы

Comment: Лень переписывать, так что [вот](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/extracting-dacpac-when-sql-server-refuses/)

Comment: @denis-rubashkin
Пытаюсь сделать через cmd по шаблону, который указан в статье, выдает ошибку "Unrecognized command line argument 'SourceConnectingString'". Нашел инструкцию по работе с SQLPackage, но при выполнении, выдается другая ошибка "Error extracting database:Could not connect to database server"